# absolute position messes everything up when trying to find clientWidth

Tags: javascript, css

Ok. So to get a clientWidth you must add code

```
#menuSystem a{
position: absolute;
height: auto;
width: auto;
font-size: 15px;
}
```

You need to do this for it to even be eligible to determine client width. What I am trying to do is set the margin-left of a description bubble related to a link to be the length of the clientWidth of the link. However when I add the "absolute" css property to the links, they get all messed up. 
How the links should be, but not the bubble: 
[image: how the links should be, but not the bubble] 
how the bubble should be but not the links
[image: how the bubble should be but not the links]so here is my JavaScript function for that

```
function hover(x){
var id = x;
var hoverBubble = document.getElementById(id);
var concat = ["menuLink", id];
var menuId = concat.join("");
var link = document.getElementById(menuId);
var linkWidth = link.clientWidth + 1;
hoverBubble.style.display = "inline";
hoverBubble.style.marginLeft = linkWidth + 'px';
}
```

Comment: This is very confusing. May be you're looking for padding-left?

Comment: no. the absolute position of the links (which is required if you want to be able to find clientWidth) messes up my links, however solves the problem for my desired margin.

Comment: Well looking at the question and the pictures you posted, I'm just not clear on what the problem actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other ways to "enable" `clientWidth`, like `float:left` or `display:inline-block`.
Did that help?